# How to translate emoji unicode bytes string to appropriate UTF-8 in PHP

Tags: php, string, unicode, utf-8, emoji

I have a string which is a unicode representation of the form: '\ud83d\ude01'. How can I translate it to its actual UTF-8 representation: ''?

I have tried the following code:

```
$emoji = '\\ud83d\\ude01';

#Cleanup
$emoji = str_replace("\\u", "", $emoji);

#Split hex
$hex_bytes = str_split($emoji, 2);
$hex_bytes_numbers = array();

#Convert to actual numbers
foreach($hex_bytes as $hex)
    array_push($hex_bytes_numbers, hexdec($hex));


$clean_hex_string = implode(array_map("chr", $hex_bytes_numbers));

#Returns: Ø=Þ
echo $clean_hex_string . "\n";

#Returns : ?=?
echo utf8_decode($clean_hex_string);
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: where is that string coming from? (in other words what is causing you to receive `'\\ud83d\\ude01'` instead of just `''`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using:

```
print json_encode('"$emoji"');
```

Found this to be the simplest method.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I get `"\"\\ud83d\\ude01\""` Can you provide more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

`\\ud83d\\ude01` looks to be an escaped form of UTF-16.

The code to unescape and decode is very simple:

```
$myInput = '\\ud83d\\ude01';

$myHexString = str_replace('\\u', '', $myInput);
$myBinString = hex2bin($myHexString);

print iconv("UTF-16BE", "UTF-8", $myBinString);
```